# How can I pass the JSON data received as a request to an external variable?

Tags: javascript, variables

I created a page with using Expressjs and Pug.
And it succeeded in fetching data using MongoDB.

However, the imported data is JSON data, so I succeeded in fetching the data using Request. However, it seems impossible to pull this data into an external variable.

I tried various things, but it keeps showing undefined or nothing on the page.

I got data from github language API (`https://api.github.com/repos/writingdeveloper/Blueinno2/languages`)

**[JavaScript Code]**

```
router.get("/:userId/:pageId", function (req, res, next) {
  // GET URL params and put it into :pageId
  let userId = req.params.userId;
  let pageId = req.params.pageId;


  Repo.find({
    'owner.login': userId,
    'name': pageId
  }, function (err, repoData) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    // console.log(repoData);
    console.log(repoData[0].name)
    let URL = repoData[0].languages_url;

    let keywordData;  // Create empty keywordData Object
    request.get({
      url: URL,
      json: true,
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'request'
      }
    }, (err, res, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error:', err);
      } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
        console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
      } else {
        console.log(data)     // It works!!!
        keywordData = data;   // Tried to save data to keywordData variable
      }
    });

    console.log(keywordData);  // Problem. It returns undefined

    res.render("detail", {
      userId: userId,
      pageId: pageId,
      projectName: repoData.name,
      keyword: keywordData,    // keywordData is undefined so this is also not working
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: Try debugging your code.  Set a breakpoint on the line where you set keywordData and on the line with the problem and see which one gets executed first.

Comment: Move `let keywordData` to before `Repo.find`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making you request synchronus.

Your res.render function gets called before the request is done so the variable you want to use is still empty.
If you make your request synchronus, the code after the request will only execute when the request is done.